# sinon stub.withArgs() for stubing external function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm new with the js unit testing and have a question about stubing things using withArgs.

I have some generic, extrernal function called "create" and I want to stub it only for some sort of arguments and for the other return values from original "create". For example:

```
stub(x,'create').withArgs(2).return(some_new_object);

not_stubbed_object = x.create(1);
stubbed_object = x.create(2);
```

In such simple code example I would like to have `stubbed_object == some_new_object` ant that works fine. But I would also like to have in `not_stubbed_object` object returned by original externatl create function. Now I have `undefined` instead.

Is there any simple solution for that or should I refactor my code to do it diferently?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood what you're trying to achieve, object.method.restore() restores the original function.